# How to remap keys on a user level both with and without X

Tags: keyboard-layout

I want to remap Capslock and I want this remap to work on both my machine with an X server and on machine without X. I also want this remap to be applied on a user level, not on a global level. [This answer](https://superuser.com/questions/194202/remapping-keys-system-wide-in-linux-not-just-in-x?lq=1) has a remap solution which works both with and without X. But the remap works globally and requires root permissions. Is it possible to remap a key locally and have it working with and without X?

Answer (score 1):

Well bummers!  I've done some research and discovered that changing the keymap to remap <kbd>CAPSLOCK</kbd> (for example) **REQUIRES** root access.  I'm sorry.

---

In the spirit of information, I'll retain what I had been working on here:

You can set up user-only keyboard configurations by putting options in `~/.keyboard`, these will override the system-wide defaults set in `/etc/default/keyboard`

- **NOTE**: to get `setupcon` to read your `~/.keyboard`, you **MUST** create `~/.console-setup`, an empty file will suffice.  The logic in `setupcon` does not check for ~/.keyboard, it looks for ~/.console-setup and then reads *both* files.  Tsk Tsk

You didn't specify what you'd like <kbd>CAPSLOCK</kbd> to be mapped to, so I'll give several examples.

You can use the `/etc/default/keyboard` file as a template if you wish, something like one of these entries in `~/.keyboard` would probably work well for you:

(remember you really only need settings which override the system defaults in `/etc/default/keyboard`)

```
XKBOPTIONS="ctrl:nocaps"     # CAPSLOCK => CTRL

XKBOPTIONS="caps:escape"     # CAPSLOCK => ESC

XKBOPTIONS="compose:caps"    # CAPSLOCK => Compose (my favorite!)
```

There are (*many*!) more options available, have a look at the man page for [`setupcon`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/1/setupcon/) (1) and the contents of the file: `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/xorg.lst` on your system.k

Comment: OH!  `~/.keyboard` and `/etc/default/keyboard` set up __BOTH__ console and X settings, a twofer.. but it's a root-twofer (twofer-root? {shrug})

Comment: Where are root permissions required if I put my configuration in `~/.keyboard`? Am I missing something?

Comment: setupcon executes loadkeys, which seems to require root privileges to modify the keyboard mapping. Try `setupcon -k -v` with and without sudo to see errors.  I didn't understand the root requirement either.